# Passing enum item to child component in template

Tags: angular

I try to pass enum item to the child compoenent:

```
 <app-enum-selection  [itemIgnore]=DataStatus.Coming_Soon ></app-enum-selection>
```

But I get this error:

```
 error TS2339: Property 'DataStatus' does not exist on type 'ConstructorComponent'.

  <app-enum-selection [itemIgnore]=DataStatus.Coming_Soon></app-enum-selection>
                                                                                                                       
  src/app/constructor/constructor.component.ts:29:16
   templateUrl: './constructor.component.html',
                    
    Error occurs in the template of component ConstructorComponent.
```

Any Idea why I get error? And how to pass enum item to child component?

Comment: Please make an executable code in stackblitz

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

**Parent Component:**

```
enum DataStatus{
    Coming_Soon,
    ...
}

export class ParentComponent {
    public dataStatus = DataStatus;        
}
```

**Child Component:**

```
export class ChildComponent {       
    @Input() public set itemIgnore(value: any) {
        console.log(value);
    };
}
```

**Parent Component Template:**

Your child component selector (assuming `app-enum-selection`) inside parent component (assuming `ConstructorComponent`) will be like this:

```
<app-enum-selection [itemIgnore]=dataStatus.Coming_Soon ></app-enum-selection>
```

**Child Component Template:**

```
<div>{{itemIgnore}}</div>
```